# vue reactivity transform $ref not defined

Tags: vue.js

According to [this](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html#refs-vs-reactive-variables) page in the docs, macros should be

> globally available and do not need to be imported when Reactivity
> Transform is enabled

I've explicitly opted-in the reactivity transforms in my vue config in accordance with the [docs here](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html#explicit-opt-in):

```js
// vue.config.js
    config.module.rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .tap((options) => {
        return {
          ...options,
          reactivityTransform: true
        }
      })
```

But I am getting the `'$ref' is not defined` from eslint. I think I need to enable it somwhere so that eslint understands it's a global macro, but I can't find anything about it in the docs.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to solve this by adding this to `.eslintrc,js`

```js
globals: {
  $ref: 'readonly',
  $computed: 'readonly',
  $shallowRef: 'readonly',
  $customRef: 'readonly',
  $toRef: 'readonly'
}
```

...and this to `global.d.ts`

```html
/// <reference types="vue/macros-global" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not already using `.eslintrc` and don't want to create one, alternative solution is to add

```
"types": [...  "vue/ref-macros"]
```

in `tsconfig.json -> compilerOptions`.

Another solution is to add `/// <reference types="vue/macros-global" />` to the top of your `src/env.d.ts` file.